# How to install GTK+ in Elementary OS Freya

Tags: unix, gtk, ubuntu-14.04, gtk3

I'm trying to install the GTK+ library on my distribution using :

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

However I get these logs (errors):

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) but 3.14.15-0ubuntu1~14.04~ricotz1 is to be installed
                Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (= 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) but 3.14.15-0ubuntu1~14.04~ricotz1 is to be installed
                Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.37.5) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.27.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.32.4) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 2.7.5) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.13.0~20140204) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libwayland-dev (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libxkbcommon-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libxi-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've recently started working on unix systems, so I don't know how to correct this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's trying to install a version of the GTK+ development files that is different from the version of GTK+ you have installed. Did you modify `/etc/apt/sources.list` or do some other upgrade task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some serious googling and reading through all the errors , I have discovered that this is a delicate situation . Apparently there is no single answer for this , and if it is it's not the right one.

I've tried the following which works :

It is recommended to use aptitude for this kind of work because aptitude offers a conflict resolver , it basically visualize unmet dependencies (and tries to solve them).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then

```
sudo aptitude install libgtk-3-dev
```

Even if this will solve the issue in most cases, it does not have a 100% succes rate.

There are differrent approaches , like cleaning up the `apt cache` , (it didn't work for me) and then using : `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev -f` , which will attempt to fix broken dependencies.

There are too many ways , all that I have learned is from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa).

**NOTE ->**
**It is possible that I have this particular issue because of my linux distro , I have read that is not very stable and it is recommended to start with some more stable and reliable versions like : Debian or Ubuntu.(for beginners)**

Comment: The last paragraph is probably closest to truth: either your operating system is pretty badly broken or you have added some package repositories that conflict with the official ones.